# GORM - add child onto parent and save is giving groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0

This is my domain model, a survey has many questions, and each question has many repsonses :

```
class Survey {

    String name
    String customerName
    static hasMany = [questions: SurveyQuestion]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class SurveyQuestion {

    String question

    static hasMany = [responses : SurveyQuestionResponse]
    static belongsTo = [survey: Survey]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class SurveyQuestionResponse {

    String description
    static belongsTo = [question: SurveyQuestion]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In my controller, I have a method that takes in the ID for a Survey, looks it up, then builds a question from another request parameter, tries to add the question to the survey and save it:

```
def addQuestion =
    {
        def question = new SurveyQuestion(question:params.question)
        def theSurvey = Survey.get(params.id)

        theSurvey.addToQuestions(question) //fails on this line
        theSurvey.save(flush:true)

        redirect(action: showSurvey, params:[id:theSurvey.id])
    }
```

However, it fails and returns this :

> No signature of method: roosearch.Survey.addToQuestions() is
>   applicable for argument types: (roosearch.SurveyQuestion) values:
>   [roosearch.SurveyQuestion : null] Possible solutions:
>   addToQuestions(java.lang.Object), getQuestions()

I'm not quite understanding what I'm doing wrong here, I've tried various alternative ways to create the question, even instantiating one manually with a literal string, but it always gives the same error.

Can anyone please advise me?

Thanks

Comment: i tried this and it seemed to work... did you try `grails clean`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. I am guessing you are writing them in an IDE and domain classes generated by the IDE are getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you dont have "question" saved so it is not in the database yet. Try to save first the "question" and then add it to the survey.
Something like this:

```
def addQuestion =
    {
        def question = new SurveyQuestion(question:params.question).save()
        def theSurvey = Survey.get(params.id)

        theSurvey.addToQuestions(question)
        theSurvey.save(flush:true)

        redirect(action: showSurvey, params:[id:theSurvey.id])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough points to comment, so I'll "answer").

First, it does look "OK".

I've learned to take the error messages at their **face value**. For some reason, it thinks that "question" is null. I'm guessing that you can insert some logging and see that it isn't.

At this point, I would try saving question first, see that it saves correctly and gets assigned and id, and then call the addToQuestions.

Answer (score 0):

can you try asserting if the SurveyQuestion actually got created using the input parameters?
e.g.

```
assert question
```

right after the line

```
def question = new SurveyQuestion(question:params.question)
```

and as suggested by #alcoholiday try some logging as well. 
or a simple

```
println params
```

could give you a quick peek